# Change Theme of .NET 4.5 WPF Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control, wpf-4.5

I am trying to change the theme of the new [WPF Ribbon Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.aspx) from .NET Framework 4.5 and I am stuck.

I only managed to change **some brushes** (Background, Foreground, Border ...) but I seem to be unable to change the bright overlay and shadows.

I am happy to use a resource dictionary but I don’t know which properties I need to set.

I hope you can point me in the right direction, thank you much for your help!

Comment: This is related btw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511416/window-style-with-wpf-ribbon-from-microsoft-doesnt-match-windows-8-style?rq=1

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change anything more than the exposed properties of the Ribbon control (or any other control) e.g. Background, Foreground etc. you will have to edit the control's **Template**.

In a control's template you can change almost anything that's part of the control's visual appearance.

For more information on customizing a control's template have a look on this link: [MSDN Styling & Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming across this, you could look at third party controls like: [Syncfusion's Ribbon](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/ribbon) (looks like the office theme)

Answer (score -2):

it is pretty simple, in your App.xaml you can define a Theme and assign this theme to any control you want. for example I had defined Office_Blue as my theme and assigned this theme only to my Button only as below:

```
  <Application.Resources>

    <telerik:Theme x:Key="TelerikGlobalTheme">Office_Blue</telerik:Theme>
      <Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="telerik:StyleManager.Theme" Value="{DynamicResource TelerikGlobalTheme}" />
      </Style>
```

you can assign as many controls as you want to that defined theme as above.

Comment: Is this for the .NET 4.5 WPF Ribbon ? The Telerik ribbon is something else.

Answer (score -5):

There are two themes as far as I know, one is for "Windows 7(default)" and the other is for "Office 2007 Blue". You can change the theme by adding a resouce dictionay to the window's resouces the source of which is the xaml file of the office 2007 Blue, like following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary 
          Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
```

You can copy the Office2007Blue.xaml to a new xaml file and modify it to create a custom theme, then reference it by following the same way as above.

You could get more about Ribbon [from here.](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx)

And if you want quick and easy solution then try this ready [WPF Themes.](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&ProjectName=wpf)

Comment: I tried this but **it doesn’t work** with the Ribbon from .NET 4.5 WPF

Comment: For that you need a separate resource dictionary to provide WPF styles to various controls. Tell me what exception you are facing exactly.

Comment: I don’t have the "RibbonControlsLibrary". I use [System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.aspx). I also tried ExpressionDark.xaml and co but they don’t change ribbon colors.

Comment: Yeah, no clue what this RibbonsControlLibrary is.  Is it some third party ribbon control? -- Pretty sure the author and everyone else is just using the built-in Microsoft one. -- I can't figure out how to theme it either.

Comment: This answer is related to RibbonControlsLibrary, not to the .NET 4.5 WPF ribbon