# WPF RibbonWindow + Windows 8 - control box looks bad

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-8, ribbon

I have a problem with WPF RibbonWindow and Windows 8. In older windows everything works fine, but on Windows 8 control box (minimalize, maximalize and exit buttons) looks terrible
[image: windows8]

I use RibbonControlLibrary from Microsoft (version from October 2010)
XAML code is included http://pastebin.com/cNws0CGt (without irrelevant information, I hope I haven't deleted something important)

Expected output (Windows 7):
[image: expected]

Comment: I figured it out, I know this is an old question but he this pops up in Google so for all the people that will see this in the future! ANSWER DOWN HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/21675624/3239917

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is the window theme.  The reason it is different in Windows 8 is because Windows 8 has a different default theme than Windows 7.  To standardize this you will need to set an explicit theme for your project.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf) on how to explicitly set your theme.

More details on what themes are available in Windows 8 [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wpf/thread/e3dd4221-af4d-4ae4-a983-895db12ebcd0).

Edit:

See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747820/net-4-5-wpf-ribbonwindow-broken-in-vs2012#details) for details on why this isn't Windows 8 themed.  It appears to be a bug that should have been fixed.  Check your .net runtime version to make sure it is the latest.

Comment: It isn't working yet. Maybe there can be problem I use .NET 4. With .NET 4.5 it works [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511416/window-style-with-wpf-ribbon-from-microsoft-doesnt-match-windows-8-style)