# WPF Ribbon Window

Tags: wpf, windows, ribbon

I am creating WPF application, I want ribbon menu like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741313/wpf-ribbonwindow-windows-8-control-box-looks-bad). I am using MahApps Metro style window. How to add a ribbon menu in the metro window. I tried lot of codings, but didn't work. So please kindly send a procedure or coding for the ribbon window. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Fluent.Ribbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon).
It's open source, should work well with MahApp.Metro and the showcase application shows both being used together.

Just download the showcase application, unzip it, run it and have a look at the tab below the ribbon which has the "Test" header. Said tab contains a button "Open MahMetro-Window" which you just have to click.

The most recent showcase application can be downloaded from [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/batzen/fluent-ribbon/build/artifacts). Please note that there is no separate zip package for the showcase application. There is only one zip package containing everything you need.

Disclaimer: I am the current maintainer of Fluent.Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon control which is similar to the Microsoft Office Ribbon Bar is available in WPF.

Check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/).

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100081/Introducing-Ribbon-UI-Control-for-WPF) also.